# Custom Manual Oauth2 Authentication at RESTful Service

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing some RESTful services for our mobile app using Spring Boot. I succesfully implemented Oauth2 authentication with our registration using username and password. Users can authenticate by using username and password. Also our client want to be authenticated with their custom token. They have a web service that you send token and response is true or false.

My first thought was, I can write a service like **/custom-login** and that service accepts custom token. In my service I can check this token with external service and if it is valid I call oauth2 authentication and return oauth2 authentication response.

How can I implement custom authentication oauth2 ?

Comment: You can use Authorization Code flow to achieve both client and user authentication. And this flow best suits mobile applications too. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2.0 spec allows for custom grant types,

So your auth server can create an custom grant type,

for eg: let's assume your wanted to authenticate with Google using Google access token, so you will create new grant_type called **google_token**

So now when your users wanted to authenticate using Google access token , they will pass like

```
grant_type=google_token&client_id=clientId&client_secret=secret&google_token=google-access-token
```

Then your auth server can verify the access token with Google and optionally verify client is issued to, etc and once verified , it can return your own access token

This applies for third party auth severs, so you can create number of custom grant types